# How do create a formula to make a curve between the lower and upper bounds?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, regression

How do I create a formula to make a curve that approaches the upper bound as the x axis steps up from 1 to 11? For example, I sell fruit and I sell an apple for $5 but I sell 2000 apples at tier 11 for $3750. How can I create pricing in between that follows the curve in the picture attached?

Chart and Table

[image: 1]

It might just be Monday, but the logic is alluding me.

Answer (score 1):

Lines similar to presented on the plot can be obtained from a formula like this:

```
y = y1 + a*b*(x-x1)/(1+b*(x-x1))
```

where `y` represent dependent variable and `x` represent independent variable (Tier).
Two points are given for each line. One point (x1, y1) has been used in the equation formula directly, the second point we can use to estimate one of the coefficients (e.g. `a`), then the other one (`b`) can be taken arbitrarily.
If we take `b` small (close to 0) the line will be almost straight, for bigger values of `b` the line becomes curved.
[image: Apples]